# Converting $.post into $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a post statement,

```
$.post("panel.php", 'data=[{"action":"UserInfo"}]', function (userInfo){
    //processing
});
```

I need it to be converted to $.ajax so made it thus,

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "panel.php",
                data:  { data: [{"action":"UserInfo"}]},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(userInfo) {
                    //processing
                }
});
```

But the post variable isn't being sent. Is this not the correct way?

Comment: `$.post is a shorthand for $.ajax[...]`, more info here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ (may be semantic nitpicking, but I think it is important to note that $.post() does NOT do a pure http POST, which would include navigation to another page)

Answer (score 3):

Can you try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "panel.php",
                data:  {"action":"UserInfo"},
                success: function(userInfo) {
                    //processing
                }
});
```

Comment: You should remove the `dataType` attribute as it is not set in the original `$.post` either so it can only lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "panel.php",
                    data: "action="+"UserInfo",
                    success: function(userInfo) {
                        //processing
                    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `data` from your `data` and keep it in a variable, stringify before your send as below

```
var data={"action":"UserInfo"};
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "panel.php",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(userInfo) {
                    //processing
                }
});
```

Comment: It's not necessary to Stringify a JSON object for `.ajax`.

Comment: @DarkAshelin. I never said its necessary. I just asked to try that way too. Who knows what way user is going to receive it on server end???

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "panel.php",
                data:  {"action":"UserInfo"},
                success: function(userInfo) {

                }
});
```

Comment: remove contentType and dataType attributes

Comment: @Lalit Sharma why have to do so ?

Comment: When you are passing values like this. Data type is not required to define

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` attribute was not written as correct JSON:

```
data:  { "data": [{"action":"UserInfo"}]},
```

You need quotation marks around the items inside your JSON object. You can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to check if your JSON object is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "panel.php",
                data:  {"action":"UserInfo"},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(userInfo) {
                    //processing
                }
});
```

Need a small change. there is a predefined format to send data in ajax,

1. data: {status: status, name: name},
2. data: "status="+status+"&name="+name.

Follow any one of the approach.